# Getting URL link of a firestore document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-dynamic-links

If I have a document in Firestore, how can I get the URL link of that document so I can use it in Dynamic Links?

There is a method called `setLink()` in the builder. If I 'm not wrong, I think I should add my own domain; but I don't have one.

So is there any way to create a dynamic link from a Firestore document link?

Comment: Do you find any solution? I do need the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question recently. I wondered how to find or construct a URL that would connect to a particular Firestore document. After modifying and testing the Firebase Console URL, I found that the document ID is already contained in the URL.

If you go into your Firebase Console, choose your required database, and then select any of the documents. Pay special attention to the URL as you select another document. The URL will change to display each document's ID.

If you are looking to provide links for end-users that contain a document ID, [Doug Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326097/getting-url-link-of-a-firestore-document#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20Firestore%20REST%20API)'s note about the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) will be most helpful. You can insert a newly-created document ID into the URL string to point the end-user directly to the required document.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't offer direct URL access to render contents of a document in a browser in a way that's suitable for end users.  You will need to build your own web application that accepts a URL and somehow renders the contents of the requested document.

There is a Firestore REST API used for programmatic access to raw document data as JSON, but that's not going to be helpful for a dynamic link that users might expect to load a normal web page into their browser.

Comment: ```You will need to build your own web application that accepts a URL and somehow renders the contents of the requested document```. How can I do that?  What I thought so far is that I can add the document ID to phpMyAdmin or any other database . But I cannot get a clear idea on how to do it